# Spring WebFlow Upgrade 2.4.5 to 2.5.0

Tags: spring, jsf, xhtml, myfaces

Hi im having some issues upgrading spring webflow.

> Spring Web Flow 2.5 documentation
>
> This release provides an upgrade path to Spring Framework 5 that in
>   turn requires Java 8+, Servlet 3.1, Hibernate 5, Tiles 3. See the
>   Spring Framework wiki for more details. The samples repository has
>   been upgraded to Spring Web Flow 2.5.
>
> As of 2.5 there is no longer a spring-js module. The classes from that
>   module have been kept but moved to new packages in the spring-webflow
>   module. The spring-js-resources module is available as an optional
>   module that must be included explicitly.
>
> This release requires JSF 2.2 or higher.

I have updated myfaces to 2.7, and servlet 3.1. I am using Spring 4 and java 8 below are my dependencies I am updating one by one.  I would also like to know how to use spring-js module explicitly.

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency
```

>

when I update the second dependency(spring-webflow) I am getting an error.
`Caused by: at java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandleradapter.getAjaxHandler()Lorg/springframework/js/ajax/AjaxHandler`

Comment: Always post full stacktraces please.

Comment: Did you post all (spring) dependencies?
Didn't look at the dependency tree, but did you try to update spring-js?